# Why terms proportional to derivative of EM $A_\mu$ field do not explicitly appear in the Dirac Eq?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, dirac-equation

In Dirac Eq in presence of EM field we normally include the minimal coupling based on $U(1)$ symmetry argument, as $$\gamma_\mu (\partial_\mu +\frac{ie}{\hbar c} A_\mu) + \frac{mc}{\hbar}.$$ Now I am wondering why we don't include the derivative of field like, $\gamma_\mu \gamma_\nu \partial_\nu A_\mu$? I understand that multiplying Dirac eq with $\gamma_\mu (\partial_\mu +\frac{ie}{\hbar c} A_\mu) - \frac{mc}{\hbar}$ give rise to $F_{\mu \nu} \sigma_{\mu\nu}$ term (which is derivative term), but I am not sure why we don't include that to Dirac Eq in the first place. This term is permitted by symmetry.